# The execution of stored procedure and triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, relational-database, database-trigger

Suppose that I have the following situation in a SQL Server database.

These are the tables on the database:

1. Table1
2. Table2

   - Associated triggers: trigger on insert (trigger1)
3. Table3

The database contains one stored procedure `sp1` (with parameters).

Now, this is how `sp1` works:

1. `sp1` is collecting some rows from `Table1` in 2 seconds
2. Depending on these row's values, maybe some rows will be inserted into `table2` (the insert takes 1 second) and off course the insert causes `trigger1` to fire
3. `trigger1` inserts or updates some rows in `Table3` (it takes 2 seconds more)
4. `sp1` is not done yet after steps 1-3, it continues to work for 2 seconds of processing and then it's finished

Imagine that there's an application (say Java, C# or whatever) calling `sp1` 100 consecutive times (the calling is much faster than the execution of `sp1`).

I want to understand how the processing flow works.

Is there any parallelism?

Does `sp1` wait for `trigger1` to finish before continue to step 4?

While calling `sp1` from the application, does every call have to wait before continuing to the next call?

Comment: You've asked 3 different questions here. Try to keep in mind that the rule is one question per post. Btw, you could set up a demo and test all of them in less time than the 1 hour that passed since you published this post....

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I think the three questions are related. I could combine them to make one question but it wouldn't be easy to be understood.
I'm setting up a demo to find out myself and if I do, off course I'll share the knowledge here to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a demo to test this situation and here's what I found:

1- sp1 always waits for the trigger before continue the rest of the processing.

2- Calling the sp1 from an application will wait for the execution to be finished unless the calling is asynchronous.